# Pretty printing with free monads and GADTs

Tags: haskell, pretty-print, gadt, free-monad

Consider the expression functor defined by the following GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

import Control.Monad.Free

data ExprF :: * -> * where
  Term :: Foo a -> (a -> r) -> ExprF r

instance Functor ExprF where
  fmap f (Term d k) = Term d (f . k)

type Expr = Free ExprF
```

where `Foo` is defined as

```
data Foo :: * -> * where
  Bar :: Int    -> Foo Int
  Baz :: Double -> Foo Double

instance Show a => Show (Foo a) where
  show (Bar j) = show j
  show (Baz j) = show j
```

The combination of the `(a -> r)` field in `ExprF` and the (otherwise desirably) restrictive GADT constructors seem to make writing a pretty printing interpreter impossible:

```
pretty (Pure r)          = show r
pretty (Free (Term f k)) = "Term " ++ show f ++ pretty (k _)
```

The type hole is what one would expect:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: a1
Where: ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
            a pattern with constructor
              Term :: forall r a. Foo a -> (a -> r) -> ExprF r,
            in an equation for ‘pretty’
            at Test.hs:23:15
Relevant bindings include
  k :: a1 -> Free ExprF a (bound at Test.hs:23:22)
  f :: Foo a1 (bound at Test.hs:23:20)
  pretty :: Free ExprF a -> String (bound at Test.hs:22:1)
In the first argument of ‘k’, namely ‘_’
In the first argument of ‘pretty’, namely ‘(k _)’
In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘pretty (k _)’
```

There seems to be no way to give the continuation a value at the type it requires.  That type is encoded in `f`, and other interpreters I'm using all handle `f` somehow to extract a value at the appropriate type.  But the path to a `String` representation seems blocked.

Is there some common idiom I'm missing here?  How would one go about pretty printing a value of `Expr`, if it is indeed even possible?  If it's not possible, what alternate construction of `ExprF` might capture the same structure, but also support a pretty printer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pattern match on `f`. If you do that, the type of `k` gets refined to match the type contained inside `Foo`:

```
pretty (Pure r)          = show r
pretty (Free (Term f k)) = "Term " ++ show f ++ pretty r where
  r = case f of
    Bar a -> k a
    Baz a -> k a
```

You might want to factor out this pattern:

```
applyToFoo :: (a -> r) -> Foo a -> r
applyToFoo f (Bar a) = f a
applyToFoo f (Baz a) = f a

pretty (Pure r)          = show r
pretty (Free (Term f k)) = "Term " ++ show f ++ pretty (applyToFoo k f)
```

Comment: You can't pattern match on a GADT in a case statement -- too hard to type.

Comment: I can here. GHC 7.8.4 and GHC 7.10.1 check it without problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll accept this answer just by virtue of it being first to the punch.

Comment: Andras, oh man, I'm showing my unhipness. Time to upgrade I guess

Comment: @luqui I'm pretty sure you've always been able to pattern-match a GADT in a `case` expression - it's `let` expressions that cause GHC to provide amusing messages about its brain exploding.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's not impossible. At the very least you can pattern match on `f`:

```
pretty :: (Show a) => Expr a -> String
pretty (Pure r) = show r
pretty (Free (Term f@(Bar x) k)) = "Term " ++ show f ++ pretty (k x)
pretty (Free (Term f@(Baz x) k)) = "Term " ++ show f ++ pretty (k x)
```

But that is not very satisfying since you already did that in `Foo`'s `show` instance.

The challenge, then, is to abstract appropriately.

Comment: /me shakes head.  One of those nights.  Thanks.